# How to run elasticsearch with transport mode in grails

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, transport

Using grails 2.0 and `runtime ":elasticsearch:0.20.6.1-SNAPSHOT"`.

Can any one tell me how can i run my application with transport mode in elasticsearch mode?

I have following configuration in my config.groovy file.

```
elasticSearch {
            /**
             * Possible values : "local", "node", "transport"
             */
            client.mode = 'transport'           
            client.transport.sniff = true
            client.hosts = [
                [host: '10.210.14.131', port: 9300]
            ]
            bulkIndexOnStartup = true
        }
```

When i do run-app it throws following error with stack trace.

```
| Error 2013-09-16 17:07:29,612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.UncategorizedExecutionException: Failed execution
Message: Error creating bean with name 'searchableClassMappingConfigurator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.UncategorizedExecutionException: Failed execution
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by UncategorizedExecutionException: Failed execution
->>  88 | rethrowExecutionException in org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    49 | actionGet in     ''
|   123 | installMappings in org.grails.plugins.elasticsearch.mapping.SearchableClassMappingConfigurator
|    50 | configureAndInstallMappings in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IndexOutOfBoundsException: Readable byte limit exceeded: 67
->> 236 | readByte in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   132 | readByte in org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.ChannelBufferStreamInput
|    35 | readByte in org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.AdapterStreamInput
|   267 | readBoolean in org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput
|   170 | readFrom in org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthRequest
|   208 | handleRequest in org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler
|   108 | messageReceived in     ''
|    70 | handleUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
|   564 | sendUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
|   791 | sendUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext
|   296 | fireMessageReceived in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels
|   462 | unfoldAndFireMessageReceived in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder
|   443 | callDecode in     ''
|   303 | messageReceived in     ''
|    70 | handleUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
|   564 | sendUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
|   791 | sendUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext
|    74 | handleUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler
|   564 | sendUpstream in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
|   559 | sendUpstream in     ''
|   268 | fireMessageReceived in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels
|   255 | fireMessageReceived in     ''
|    88 | read . . in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker
|   109 | process  in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker
|   312 | run . .  in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector
|    90 | run      in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker
|   178 | run . .  in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker
|   108 | run      in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable
|    42 | run . .  in org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys happy to tell you solution for this problem

Finally i re-build everything by replacing

```
runtime ":elasticsearch:0.20.6.1-SNAPSHOT"
to
runtime ":elasticsearch:0.90.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

And my job get done.